# Vi Regex - Column Editing

Tags: regex, vi, delimiter

I have a text with 9 columns opened in the vi-editor and I like to replace the tab characters in the 9th column (the last one) with a comma, followed by a space. So far I came up with this;

```
'2,$s#\(^.\{8\}\)\\t#\1\(\,\)#'
```

but that doesn't seem to match anything... It could be that I escaped something too much, but also I don't know if you need to specify the column delimiter (in this case also a tab).
Any help on this one would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%s/^\(\%(\t\?[^\t]\+\)\{8\}\)\t\(.*\)$/\1, \2/
```

This replaces (`s`):

- `^` - start of the line
- `\(` start of **(group 1)**

  - `\%(` start of inner group

    - `\t?` 0 or more <kbd>Tab</kbd>s (to account for the lack of a <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the start of the line)
    - `[^\t]\+` followed by 1 ore more non-<kbd>Tab</kbd>s
  - `\)` end of inner group
  - `\{8\}` the above inner group repeated 8 times
- `\)` end of **(group 1)**
- `\t` followed by a <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- `\(.*\)` and whatever else **(group 2)**
- `$` until the end of the line

with:

- `\1` - **(group 1)** (everything up until the 8th <kbd>Tab</kbd>)
- `,`  - a comma and a space
- `\2` - **(group 2)** (everything from the 8th <kbd>Tab</kbd> until the end of the line)

in the whole buffer (`%`).

Comment: I think I might have malexplained myself... The columns are separated by tabs; but the last column contains also tabs, whereas the others dont.

Comment: Helped me fix the rest... Had to do some minor tweaks, but your explanation of the whole thing cleared up a lot :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a one-off replacement, you could use a macro instead (starting in the first character of the first line you wish to change):

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

Where the keypresses are as follows:

- <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> – start recording a macro in register *q*
- <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> – find the first tab character (i.e. between columns 1 and 2)
- <kbd>7</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> – repeat this find seven times (i.e. to the tab character between columns 8 and 9)
- <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> – change the Tab character to a comma and a space
- <kbd>j</kbd> – go down one line
- <kbd>0</kbd> – go to the beginning of this line
- <kbd>q</kbd> – stop recording the macro

Then use <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to play it back for the next line (or <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to play it back for the next 99 lines, etc.).

Comment: Or, after the first `@q`, you can continue with `@@` (just keep `@` pressed until every line is processed).